# acfdist.ltraj function in adehabitatLT

Tags: r

I'm working with the [adehabitatLT package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adehabitatLT/index.html) of R and have encountered an issue with the `acfdist.ltraj` function.  I made a regular trajectory of my data, which introduces NA's.  When trying to run the `acfdist.ltraj` function I receive the following error message:

> Error in quantile.default(res$sim, probs=c(0.025, 0.5, 0.975)): missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE.

My question is how do I handle the `NA` values introduced to the data to enable this function to work?

Thank you,
Chris Harvey

Comment: That function name looks like somebody slammed their face onto the keyboard.

Comment: a reproducible example would help a lot.  http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000

Comment: Based on the error message, and without ever having used that function, I'd say add an `na.rm=TRUE` parameter to the function call.